How to change the font weight of h2 in angular material m3?
I set the font weight in theme and expected it would get applied to all elements:
$theme: mat.define-theme((
  ...
  typography: (
    plain-family: 'Roboto, sans-serif',
    brand-family: 'Roboto, sans-serif',
    bold-weight: 400,
    medium-weight: 400,
    use-system-variables: true,
  ),
));
...
html {
  @include mat.all-component-themes($theme);
}

:root {
  @include navigation-theme.theme($theme, $variant-colors);

  @include mat.typography-hierarchy($theme);
  @include mat.system-level-colors($theme);
  @include mat.system-level-typography($theme);
}

I would expect that all elements like h1,h2... now have a font weight of 400 but this is not the case.

If you want to apply the weight to h1, h2, h3, etc. Then you need to set it for regular-weight.
@use '@angular/material' as mat;

$theme: mat.define-theme(
  (
    color: (
      theme-type: light,
      primary: mat.$azure-palette,
      tertiary: mat.$blue-palette,
    ),
    typography: (
      plain-family: 'Roboto, sans-serif',
      brand-family: 'Roboto, sans-serif',
      bold-weight: 500,
      medium-weight: 500,
      regular-weight: 500, // <- changed here!
      use-system-variables: true,
    ),
  )
);

body {
  @include mat.all-component-themes($theme);
  font-family: Roboto, 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 30px;
  height: 100%;
}
:root {
  // @include navigation-theme.theme($theme, $variant-colors);

  @include mat.typography-hierarchy($theme);
  @include mat.system-level-colors($theme);
  @include mat.system-level-typography($theme);
}
html {
  height: 100%;
}

@include mat.core();
@include mat.color-variants-backwards-compatibility($theme);

HTML:
<h1>h1</h1>
<h2>h2</h2>
<h3>h3</h3>
<h4>h4</h4>
<h5>h5</h5>
<h6>h6</h6>

Stackblitz Demo

Thanks for your answer. I'm not able to run the stackblitz (yarn/npm i fails) but run it on my local machine. Font weight in all h tags is 400, although it is set to 500 in your code.

@MarcS82 You have a option to download the stackblitz code to local and run it, could you try it this way, because I did an inspect element and 500 was applied to the font

I think the h tags are not affected anymore by material typography. Correct answer would be to use the classes like .mat-display-medium I guess.

@MarcS82 Yeah like my answer to your earlier question, but its working on my current answer stackblitz :)
